# "as green" or "with green": which one is correct?

Tags: word-usage

Which one of the following two sentences is correct/proper?

> I finished some of the items and marked them **as green** in the list.

or

> I finished some of the items and marked them **with green** in the list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"As green" suggests that the items themselves have been made green (e.g., their font color is now green), whereas "with green" simply suggests that you marked the items using a green color (e.g., with a green highlighter).

If this is used in the context of spreadsheet software, for example, I would probably prefer "I finished some of the items and changed them to green in the list," since that more clearly emphasizes that you changed their color. If you just have a hand-written list of items and you're marking items in different colors based on status, I would use "with green" over "as green."

Comment: Would leaving it out entirely also be correct, because that sounds logical to me (I am not native english). "I finished some of the items and marked them green in the list."

Comment: Yes, that works as well. In my experience, when referring to a list of todo's, people would phrase it like "I checked off some items from my todo list."

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it I finished some of the items and marked `them green` in the list. so that `marked` stands for the item? I'm myself from Germany, so I'm not completely sure.